# Outputting each chapter of a LaTeX document to a separate PDF

Tags: pdftex, output

Is it possible to output each chapter of a LaTeX document to a separate PDF? I have a document with 10 chapters and I would like to get 10 PDFs when I compile my document. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: TeX can only make one pdf, but you can make each chapter a separate document (there are various ways to fix up cross referencing and numbering in such cases)

Comment: If you already have your ten chapters as one file you could just generate a _single_ pdf and then extract out the various pages directly for the PDF.

Comment: Free tools like pdftk can split a pdf into multiple files. The downside is that you have to hand the pagenumbers to the command. The moment they change you have to adapt the command.